# Unable to resize image using dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, dropzone.js

I can't get dropzone.js to resize images before upload. I am using the latest version 5.7.1. Here is my config below. All the other config options are respected, except the resizeWidth option. **I am not overiding the transformFile function**.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

const dropzoneForm = new Dropzone("#upload", {
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    resizeWidth: 120
});
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, and I also tried to use transformFile and it's not working.

Comment: Did you figure this out?